# Linux command to extract a text

Tags: linux, sed

Text:

```
All rights reserved. ERROR: ORA-00257: archiver error. Connect internal only, error. SP2-0751: Unable to connect to oracle. Exiting SQL*Plus
```

My intended output:

```
ERROR: ORA-00257: archiver error.
```

My command:

```
sed 's/.*\(ERROR:.*\.\).*/\1/'
```

Actual Output:

```
ERROR: ORA-00257: archiver error. Connect internal only, error. SP2-0751: Unable to connect to oracle.
```

How can i tweak my sed command to display only this:

```
ERROR: ORA-00257: archiver error.
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of taking all characters (`.*`) followed by a dot, you should rather take "all characters except a dot" (`[^\.]*`) followed by a dot:

```
sed 's/.*\(ERROR:[^\.]*\.\).*/\1/'
```

Answer (score 0):

Sed use greedy match by default and it seems that sed doesn't support non-greedy match, so it will match as long as possible.

You can change `.*\.` in the parenthesis into `[^.]*\.` to match a non-dot character then follow a dot, this should behave like non-greedy match. Or you can use a more powerfull regex engine like perl:

`perl -pe 's/.*(ERROR:.*?\.).*/\1/'`

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve the same with `sed`

```
$ sed -r 's/.*(ERROR[^.]*\.).*/\1/' log

ERROR: ORA-00257: archiver error.
```